# how to use distinct operator

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

would you please let me know the reason why I am getting the output mentioned below??
I expected to get the following out put:

```
[Person(_name=xyz4, _age=30),   
Person(_name=xyz5, _age=50)]
```

because of distinct operator

**Main**:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val person1 = Person("xyz1", 10);
val person2 = Person("xyz2", 20);
val person3 = Person("xyz3", 30);
val person4 = Person("xyz4", 30);
val person5 = Person("xyz5", 50);

var persons = listOf(
person1, person2, person3, person4 , person5)
.asSequence()
.filter { x-> x.age >=30 }
.distinct()

println(persons.toList())
}
```

**output**:

```
[Person(_name=xyz3, _age=30), Person(_name=xyz4, _age=30), 
Person(_name=xyz5, _age=50)]
```

Comment: you can use `sequenceOf` instead of `listOf`

Comment: because your `person4` has age of 60

Comment: `distinct` removes duplicates, but there are no duplicates. Why do you think it should remove `Person(_name=xyz3, _age=60)`?

Comment: Note that the output doesn't match the input. there is no person with name xyz3 and age 60 in your input. So you're probably not getting the output you posted, or you probably didn't use the inpt you posted.

Comment: @RahulKumar i updated the question..please have a look

Comment: @marstran i updated the question..please have a look

Comment: @JBNizet please have a look I update dthe question7

Comment: @LetsamrIt Where does `Person(_name=xyz4, _age=30)` come from? That person doesn't exist in your input list.

Comment: Voting to close since, despite our requests, you're not posting the actual code and/or output.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
.distinctBy { it.age }
```

instead of

```
.distinct()
```

if order of elements is important you can add sortedBy like this

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val person1 = Person("xyz1", 10)
    val person2 = Person("xyz2", 20)
    val person3 = Person("xyz3", 30)
    val person4 = Person("xyz4", 30)
    val person5 = Person("xyz5", 50)

    val persons = listOf(
            person1, person2, person3, person4, person5)
            .reversed()
            .filter { x -> x.age >= 30 }
            .distinctBy { it.age }
            .sortedBy { it.age }

    println(persons.toList())
}
```